# Xcode 6 Push segues are deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: xcode, xcode6, segue

I've upgraded to Xcode 6 and now I have an issue in the issue navigator.

```
"Push segues are deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later"
```

How do I update the segue to remove the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Select the segue in the outline view.

Open up the Attributes Inspector from the Utility pane.

Choose the "Show (e.g. Push)" option from the Segue drop down.

Comment: This will make the push become a modal for iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

If we keep "Show(e.g. Push)" the navigation bar didn't show to the destination screen. It presented the screen modally in iOS7 since my app has a deployment target iOS7.0. It must support iOS7.0 and later versions.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and is poorly written (grammar, language).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the warning and still need to support iOS7, just uncheck "Use Size Classes" checkbox in File Inspector for your storyboard or xib. Size classes are not supported in iOS7 anyway (as well as adaptive segues), and disabling this will allow you to use "deprecated" segues like "push" without warnings.